# Reset AutoNumber(Identity Field) in Database

Tags: sql-server-ce, identity

I Use a Sql Server **Compact Edition** Database File For Store the Data in My Windows Application Software.

In this database I have a table with an identity field.

When I insert a record into the Table, the identity code increments automatically. But when I delete all the records from the table, and insert some records again, the identity field doesn't start at 1.

How can I reset this value to 1?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

DBCC does not exist in CE, but you can use this instead:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ALTER COLUMN id IDENTITY (1,1)
```